# End of Stream encountered before parsing was completed. while Deserializing in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am getting **error:**

> End of Stream encountered before parsing was completed while deserializing the file

**code:**

```
Dim fs As FileStream = Nothing

  Try
    fs = IO.File.OpenRead(Filename)
    'fs = New FileStream(Filename, FileMode.Open)


      Dim bf As New Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter()

      bf.AssemblyFormat = Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.FormatterAssemblyStyle.Full
      bf.TypeFormat = Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.FormatterTypeStyle.TypesWhenNeeded
      fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
      Dim obj As Object = bf.Deserialize(fs)
      Return obj
  Catch ex As Exception
       MsgBox("There was an exception while trying to convert binary file to object. Exception: " & ex.Message & " | Stacktrace: " & ex.StackTrace)
  Finally
      If fs IsNot Nothing Then
         fs.Close()
      End If
 End Try
```

I have tried with `fs.Position=0` also even it is not working.

Any one can help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The error is probably in serializing part of code.
Please for now get rid of Format properties in both procedures and make sure you were using `using` everywhere where possible so that all bytes of all streams, writers, readers and their wrappers have been flushed.

Comment: Thanks and can you please post me the standard code for both procedures. what are the format properties shall i use?

Comment: I never use them at all.

Comment: Please post your code for serialization so we can see. I'm not fluent in vv.net anymore but we might find something quick if you show your code.

Comment: Dim fs As FileStream = Nothing
            'Dim fs As FileStream = IO.File.OpenWrite(Filename)
            Try
                fs = New FileStream(Filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
                Dim stream As New MemoryStream()
                Dim bf As New Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter()
                bf.AssemblyFormat = Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.FormatterAssemblyStyle.Full
                bf.TypeFormat = Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.FormatterTypeStyle.TypesWhenNeeded
                bf.Serialize(fs, data)
            Catch ex As Exception

Comment: You see, you have no Dispose, nowhere.